# Rollback doesn't work for my standalone Spring app

Tags: spring, transactions, rollback

I am working on a standalone spring/jpa/hibernate application.

The problem I am experiencing is that my app won't rollback transactions even though a RuntimeException is raised.

Here is my config:

```
 <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jeanbaptistemartin"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
    <bean id="gestionnaireMailing" class="com.jeanbaptistemartin.desktop.JFrameGestionnaireMailing" init-method="init" >

    </bean>

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
        <property name="shared" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${mail.server}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${mail.port}"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.connectiontimeout">2000</prop>    
                <prop key="mail.smtp.timeout">2000</prop>    
            </props>    
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
            <value>
            resource.loader=class
            class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jbmPU" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="${database.showSql}" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="${database.generateDdl}"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.dialect}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
        <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

My transactional method:

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {RuntimeException.class})
    public boolean mailAbonne(List<Sculpture> sculpturesChoisiesPourMailing, Abonne abonne) {
        try {
            for (Sculpture sculpture : sculpturesChoisiesPourMailing) {
                MailingAbonnePK mapk = new MailingAbonnePK(sculpture.getSculptureID(), abonne.getAbonneID());
                MailingAbonne ma = new MailingAbonne(mapk, new Date());
                dao.persistMailingAbonnee(ma);
            }
            envoyerMail(sculpturesChoisiesPourMailing, abonne);//this method sometimes throws a RuntimeException.
            return true;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            log.error("Exception");
            log.error(e);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
```

In my dao:

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Now a word about the current behaviour of my app:

when a RuntimeException or a subclass thereof is raised by envoyerMail the apps just hangs indefinitely.

Now another word about the desired behaviour of my app.

My mailAbonne method is called in a loop as follows:

```
 for (Abonne abonne : totalAbonnes) {
   mailAbonne(sculpturesChoisiesPourMailing, abonne);
}
```

Ideally I would like for **one iteration of the loop to fail or succeed atomically** i.e. if a RuntimeException is raised at iteration 3 out of a total of 5 iterations, I would then have in my database data corresponding to the 4 successfull iterations and the data corresponding to the failed iteration would be rolledback.

Can anyone please help?

J.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to specify `rollbackFor = {RuntimeException.class}`. The default behavior is to rollback for any runtime exception.

Your problem seems to be that you're calling your transactional method from another method of the same bean. Spring starts and stops transactions automatically because it wraps every bean inside a proxy which handles this transaction work. When you're calling a method from the same bean, the proxy can't intercept the call and start/stop a transaction for you. You should thus put the transactional method in another bean.

Then for your iteration. In order to work you need

- to make the method containing the loop not transactional, so that every call to mailAbonne starts a new transaction
- or to make the propagation of the mailAbonne method REQUIRES_NEW, in order to make it have its own independent transaction

Of course, you also need to wrap every call of mailAbonne in the loop inside a try/catch block, so that runtime exceptions are caught and the next call to mailAbonne can be done even if the current one has failed.

Comment: Many thanks JB Nizet! I was not aware of this in Spring. Your advice sorted the problem. Thanks again, Julien.